# Splitting Features, based on polygon

Tags: qgis

I'm working on a qgis project, where I have shapefiles : one is a polygon of the area of interest, the other one is a point type file.

I need to split the polygon file based on a number of points.  For example, every 2000 points will cover one tile of the polygon.
So for 10000 points, I'll divide my polygon into 5 tiles each covering an area of 2000 points.

How can I perform this task automatically, instead of drawing lines to cut polygon everytime ?

Comment: I guess there's a myriad of ways to split a polygon by taking clusters of 2000 points... If you need regular geographic divisions, consider using a grid.

Comment: Thank you for your brief answer, but i'm kind of new to GIS, especially Qgis, so could you provide me with a bit more detailled guide ?

Thank you again.

Comment: What is the distribution of your points spatially? Are they clustered or uniformly dispersed? Does that 2000 points per tile need to be really close or is  a range, say 1500 to 2500 acceptable?

Comment: Here's a screenshot of my shapefiles :    (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1o6zzOEy5oFU6mH4GFalPLajsWdNpoyBb)



As you can see there's no special distrubition, and also the polygon **LAL69-plaque** is the one i need to split in different tiles.

Comment: Also i can't use the grid because i don't need the tiles to be spatially uniform as this won't give me the desired result